# Prevent HTML character encoding when outputting a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, concatenation

I'm trying to output a string in my ruby on rails `View`:

```
<% @myquiz.map do |x| %>

    <%= "<div>#{x.quiz_ID}</div>" %>

<% end %>
```

For some odd reason it is outputting in the HTML safe formatting:

```
&lt;div&gt;14&lt;/div&gt;

&lt;div&gt;16&lt;/div&gt;
```

How do I prevent this behaviour so that it is outputting as HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= "<div>#{x.quiz_ID}</div>".html_safe %>
```

will give you the required output.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= raw "<div>#{x.quiz_ID}</div>" %>
```